# Can't run projects in QtCreator 2.8.1...?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I used QtCreator on Elementary OS Luna for quite some time, then I had to reinstall the system. After clean install I installed Qt SDK from https://qt-project.org/downloads.

I created a sample, template project and hit Run. There was an error about no compiler set... so I installed g++ via `sudo apt-get install g++`.

OK, I pushed it a bit further. Now I am getting two errors:

```
:-1: błąd:cannot find -lGL
:-1: błąd:collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I go into Tools -> Options... I can see that it set GCC as compiler automatically and that there is some error in "manually set" (though I did not set enything). It links to: `/usr/bin/qmake-qt4`. And the error near it is: `No qmake or it is not an executable` (or something similiar, I am using Polish language for QtCreator).

Then I decided to install `sudo apt-get install build-essential` but still nothing changed... shall I manually install qmake or something...? And what about the errors... does it has something to do with OpenGL? I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message that you posted (`cannot find -lGL`) comes from the linker, which runs after the compiler. This means, that you were able to compile the project, but the linker failed, because it cannot find the library `libGL.so`.

I am unfortunately not sure which package you should install to get that library. But you can try to install `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev freeglut3-dev`.

*Edit*: I updated the installation instruction according to the solution that [galkowskit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2420731/galkowskit) provided himself.

Comment: There is no such a package unfortunately. Elementary OS Luna is Ubuntu 12.04LTS derivative if that helps. I tried to find such a package with Synaptic Package Manager but after searching for "gl dev", "opengl dev" or "libgl" there is just way too many packages for a random try. :(

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev`
`sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev`

OK, I found that these two packages contain `gl.h` and `glut.h` could it be that this is what I am looking for?

Comment: Yes! I installed those two packages, they pulled some dependencies but it works now. Great! Thanks for pointing into right direction guys! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes it definitely have something to do with OpenGL, to be more precise that you're missing the libraries for it. You need to install the development packages for OpenGL.